Line chart including zero count using MediaWiki & Semantic Results Formats
I'm Trying to convert a table to line chart using Semantic MediaWiki & SRF. I have a list of Items with Color and Year of production properties. I created a table query displaying Red items produced each year:
{{#ask:
  [[Color::Red]]
 |?Year
 |mainlabel=Item
}}

Resulting in:



Item
Year




Red Item 1
1991


Red Item 2
1993


Red Item 3
1993


Red Item 4
1997



Now I'd like to make a line chart to show how many red items were produced each year between 1990-2000, displaying zero items for years with no red items, meaning, without omitting any year from the x-axis.
This is my jqplotchart chart query, but naturally it displays only the years appearing in the table.
{{#ask:
  [[Color::Red]]
|?Year
|mainlabel=-
|format=jqplotchart
|charttype=line
|distribution=yes
|datalabels=value
}}

Obviously a different approach is needed. Any ideas?

Ended up using a more elaborate code using Count result format, Widget extension and charts.js.
